# How to send and display image from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My project have two controllers: mvc and api. Image is passed from view to mvc controller successfully and the problem is how can i send it from mvc controller to api controller?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(ProductSubCategoryviewmodel productSubCategory)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = UploadedFile(productSubCategory);
                ProductSubCategoryviewmodel category = new ProductSubCategoryviewmodel();
            {
                category.ProductSubCategoryName = productSubCategory.ProductSubCategoryName;
                category.Rate = productSubCategory.Rate;
                category.DisplayOrder = productSubCategory.DisplayOrder;
                category.Image = uniqueFileName;
            };               
        }

        HttpClient client = api.FromApi();
        var prosubjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productSubCategory);
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prosubjson);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        try
        {
            var result = client.PostAsync("api/ProductSubCategories", byteContent).Result;
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    private string UploadedFile(ProductSubCategoryviewmodel productSubCategory)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = null;

        if (productSubCategory.Image != null)
        {
            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images");
            uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + productSubCategory.Image;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                productSubCategory.Image.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        return uniqueFileName;
    }
```

It shows error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'destination' of 'string.CopyTo(int, char[], int, int)'.*emphasized text*

Comment: Why do you need to pass it to the API controller? If the reason is because you want to re-use the logic in your API controller, maybe you can create a Service layer instead that can be consume both by your API and MVC controller.

Comment: thank you for your advice, can you help me by sending sample code ?

Comment: You can check my post answer.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and just to give an idea it can be something like this.

```
public class MyService
{
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        // Logic code here
    }
}

public class MyApiController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyApiMethod()
    {
        MyService myService = new MyService();
        myService.MyTestMethod();
    }
}

public class MyMVCController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyMVCMethod()
    {
        MyService myService = new MyService();
        myService.MyTestMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: there are two different projects one in mvc and another in api

Answer (score 0):

> How to send and display image from view to controller?

According to your code, I suppose you are using the IFormFile to send Image from view to the controller, but I'm not sure which DataType you are using to store in the database, base64 string or byte array. In my opinion, I prefer to use byte array to store the upload file.

More detail information, please check the following code:

Code in the model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public byte[] Poster { get; set; }
}
```

and the view model (using this ViewModel to upload file to controller)

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile PosterImage { get; set; }
}
```

Code in the Controller:

```
  // GET: Movies/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Movies/Create 
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MovieViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            Movie movie = new Movie
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Genre = model.Genre,
                ReleaseDate = model.ReleaseDate,
                Price = model.Price,
            };
            if (model.PosterImage != null)
            { 
                using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    model.PosterImage.CopyTo(target);
                    movie.Poster = target.ToArray(); //get the image byte array
                }
            }
            _context.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Code in the Index view (using the Movie model, instead of the MovieViewModel):

using `<img>` tag to display the image.

```
@model IEnumerable<dotNetCore3_1.Models.Movie>
 
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            ...
            <td>
                @if (item.Poster != null)
                {

                    <img class="img-responsive  " style="width:50px; height:50px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Poster)" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img class="img-responsive " style="width:50px; height:50px" src="~/images/default.jpg" />
                } 
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> how can i send it from mvc controller to api controller?

To send data to an API action method from the MVC controller, you can use the HttpClient() method, and transfer the object json string to the API controller. Code like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MovieViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            Movie movie = new Movie
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Genre = model.Genre,
                ReleaseDate = model.ReleaseDate,
                Price = model.Price,
            };
            if (model.PosterImage != null)
            { 
                using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    model.PosterImage.CopyTo(target);
                    movie.Poster = target.ToArray(); //stored the image using byte array.
                }
            }
            //consume the webapi and post the model.
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var requesturi = "https://localhost:44334/api/MoviesAPI";
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                //HTTP POST
                var postTask = client.PostAsync(requesturi, content);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            //_context.Add(movie);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Code in the API controller method:

```
    // POST: api/MoviesAPI
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Movie>> PostMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        _context.Movie.Add(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetMovie", new { id = movie.Id }, movie);
    }
```

Finally, the screenshot as below:

[image]